# Windows 10 does not boot after udate KB5001330

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

my PC does not boot anymore after updating to Microsoft Update KB5001330 where I get a BSoD, and the autofix solution does not work.

(In the following trouble shooting paths could be some translation errors, I have to translate it from German to English, and I'm not sure if I'm using the right translation)

I tried to uninstall the update in `Advanced boot options -> troubleshoot -> advanced options -> Uninstall Updates -> Unistall latest quality update` which does not work.

I tried to uninstall the update in `Boot in Safe mode -> Settings -> Update and Security -> Windows Update`, but there I cant see any options, because in this window I got an error message, I should try to open the settings later.

I tried to uninstall it from `Boot in Safe Mode -> Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Show Installed Updates` and when I uninstall the Security update I get an error message "An Error occured. Not all updates could be uninstalled".

And last thing I tried was to uninstall it  from the Powershell (Admin) with `WUSA /UNINSTALL /KB:5001330` when booted in Safe Mode where i got the error message that an error occured with errormessage `0x800f0905`, where i can't find a solution on the web for this error message.

Has someone another idea how i can boot my windows again?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you are updating to install an update released more than a month ago?

Comment: I just got the update notification yesterday ...

Comment: This a corporate machine?  The update was released in April and there have been two updates since it was released.  The real answer to your question, unfortunately, is likely that your HDD is likely failing.  The only Windows booting problems I have had were always caused by failing drive.

Comment: Indeed, there is an error on my boot SSD, when I do a disk check in the properties menu... thanks for pointing that out...

Comment: Given the SSD is showing an error, and this is a corporate machine, best leave it to your IT Administrator to resolve.

Comment: Use Windows System Restore from the advanced menu, pick a date before the update was applied.